# Gridview doesn't update insert/update commands

Tags: vb.net, gridview, detailsview

I have a gridview that is set to a sql datasource, it is generating the columns automatically. If I add a column to the table it is referencing, it will draw that column and display it, but it does not update the insert/update commands to include the new column. Is there any way have it rebuild those commands automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update the insert/update commands to specify the parameters, the only reason I can think that your gridview is showing the column after you have added it to the table is because your select command is doing a `select * from [table]`

Comment: It is, but it generates the insert and update statements correctly the first time, so is there no way to have it figure out what the statement should be updated to?

Comment: The tooling/IDE is only populating the select,insert and update commands when you tell it to do, it won't check the database automatically for changes.